# Best Spring batch scaling strategy

Tags: spring, parallel-processing, spring-batch, scalability

We have simple batch processes which are working fine. Recently we have new reqmnt to implement new batch process to generate reports. We have diff source of data to read to prepare this reports. Specifically we might have one view for each report.

Now we want to scale this process in such a way that, it can be scaled and be completed as early as possible.

I am familiar with multithread step but not sure about other strategy(Remote chunking and partition step) and which one to use when.

In our case processing + writing to file is more resource incentive then reading.

In such cases which approach is best suited.

Or if we find out that reading data from db is same resource incentive as writing + processing to file then what is the best option we have to improve/scale this process.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**TLDR;**

Based on your description I think you could try Multi-threaded Step with Synchronized Reader since you mention processing and writing are the more expensive part of your step.

However, seeing as your reader is a database, I think getting a partitioned step configured and working would be very beneficial. It takes a little more work to get set up but will scale better in the long run.

### [Multi-threaded Step](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep)

**Use For:**

- Speeding up an individual step
- When load balancing can be handled by reader (i.e. JMS or AMQP)
- When using custom reader that manually partitions the data being read

**Don't Use For:**

- Stateful item readers

Multi-threaded steps utilize the [chunk-oriented processing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#chunkOrientedProcessing) employed by Spring Batch. When you multi-thread a step it allows spring batch to execute an entire *chunk* in it's own thread. Note that this means the entire read-process-write cycle for your chunks of data will occur in parallel. This means there is no guaranteed order for processing your data. Also note that this will **not** work with stateful ItemReaders ([JdbcCursorItemReader](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcCursorItemReader.html) and [JdbcPagingItemReader](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.html) are both stateful).

#### Multi-threaded Step with Synchronized Reader

**Use For:**

- Speeding up processing and writing for an individual step
- When reading is stateful

**Don't Use For:**

- Speeding up reading

There is one way around the limitation of not being able to use multi-threaded steps with stateful item readers. You can `synchronize` their `read()` method. This will essentially cause reads to happen serially (still no guarantee on order though) but still allow processing and writing to happen in parallel. This can be a good option when reading is not the bottleneck but processing or writing is.

### [Partitioning](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning)

**Use For:**

- Speeding up an individual step
- When reading is stateful
- When input data can be partitioned

**Don't Use For:**

- When input data cannot be partitioned

Partitioning a step behaves slightly different than a multi-threaded step. With a partitioned step you actually have complete distinct [StepExecutions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/domain.html#domainStepExecution). Each StepExecution works on it's own partition of the data. This way the reader does not have problems reading the same data because each reader is only looking at a specific slice of the data. This method is extremely powerful but is also more complicated to set up than a multi-threaded step.

### [Remote Chunking](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html#remoteChunking)

**Use For:**

- Speeding up processing and writing for an individual step
- Stateful readers

**Don't Use For:**

- Speeding up reading

Remote chunking is very advanced Spring Batch usage. It requires to have some form of durable middleware to send and receive messages on (i.e. JMS or AMQP). With remote chunking, reading is still single-threaded but as each chunk is read it is sent to another JVM for processing. In practice this is very similar to how a multi-threaded step works however remote chunking can utilize more than one **process** as opposed to more than one **thread**. This means that remote chunking allows you to *horizontally* scale your application as opposed to *vertically* scaling it. (TBH I think if you are thinking about implementing remote chunking, you should consider taking a look at something like Hadoop.)

### [Parallel Step](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html#scalabilityParallelSteps)

**Use For:**

- Speeding up overall job execution
- When there are independent steps that don't rely on each other

**Don't Use For:**

- Speeding up step execution
- Dependent steps

Parallel steps are useful when you have on or more steps that can execute independently. Spring batch can easily allow steps to execute in parallel in seperate threads.

Comment: is parallel step scenario totally ruled out for dependent steps? In my case, parallel steps make more sense even if being dependent because step#1 dumps data to a temp db table and step#2 should pick data from temp table and do processing. Is it possible for step#2 reader to poll db table? are there any such readers? Job this way makes more sense because step#1 takes very long time to produce output but when it does we wish to process it in step #2 immediately. Not willing to plug in step # 2 in step #1 processor due to db reads and writes.

Comment: @SabirKhan Short answer to your question is, there are no OOTB components that could handle what you describe. I could see developing a custom DB reader, but you would have to figure some way to 'notify' step 2 that step 1 is done. It sounds more like step 2 should be a long-running-process that is watching the DB for changes and doing some processing. Maybe it makes more sense for step 1 to publish to a persistent topic instead of DB? Then you can have 'push' notifications when new data is available rather than having to poll. Lots of options but I don't think parallel step is your solution.

Comment: I would also list [AsyncItemProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#asynchronous-processors) as an alternative to SynchronizedItemStreamReader.  It is often forgotten because it belongs to spring-batch-integration.